# Error notifying registry change listener. Invalid registry object after installing Google Plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-3.6, helios

(I've installed JDK 1.6 + Eclipse HELIOS)

After installing Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.6 , I restarted Eclipse and found:

1. Google Sign-in doesn't work ( gives an OAuth error, saying invalid client_id )
2. The Google toolbar  doesn't show up.
3. The (Google)Web Application option from New Project doesn't show up.

So, I uninstalled the plugin(It showed up in the plugins list).

I installed it again and this time: I chose to "APPLY CHANGES" instead of "RESTART" eclipse right after installation completed.

I see the following error when I did so.

"Error notifying registry change listener. Invalid registry object"

Screenshot: 
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Lh0-6WQSouI/TxBqsIJScAI/AAAAAAAAAPo/9oa9KuHhyis/s1600/gae-eclipse-issue.jpg

I installed EGIT . It worked fine. I'm using a Windows 7 box.

Please suggest me a workaround.